# How to save trained FCN model and test new image on trained FCN model?

Tags: python, keras

I am using this code to train FCN, I have succssfully run this code. However, I want to test new images on this trained model, can anyone help me?

```py
#Training

from keras import optimizers

sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=1E-2, decay=5**(-4), momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
optimizer=sgd,
metrics=['accuracy'])

hist1 = model.fit(X_train,y_train,
validation_data=(X_test,y_test),
batch_size=2,epochs=20,verbose=1)

for key in ['loss', 'acc', 'val_loss', 'val_acc']:
plt.plot(hist1.history[key],label=key)
plt.legend()
plt.show()


y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
y_predi = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=3)
y_testi = np.argmax(y_test, axis=3)
print(y_testi.shape,y_predi.shape)
```

Comment: Please add indentation to your code

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the keras FAQs (https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model):

To save your model to your disk you can do:

```
model.save("my_model_file.h5")
```

And to load it again later or in another file for using it:

```
from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model("my_model_file.h5")
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```